# App crash error Requires com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission

Tags: android

Hello I am working on a launcher that is based off of launcher3 form ASOP it runs just on all my devices that are not running cyanogenmod when I try to install it on a device that runs cyanogenmod it loads for a minute and then crashes

heres what the logcat says:

```
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845): FATAL EXCEPTION: launcher-loader
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845): Process: com.d4a.tobiasnow, PID: 9845
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.launcher3.LauncherProvider uri content://com.android.launcher3.settings/favorites/18?notify=false from pid=9845, uid=10093 requires com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, or grantUriPermission()
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:568)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1333)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at com.d4a.tobaisnow.LauncherModel$5.run(LauncherModel.java:526)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-03 10:32:26.665: E/AndroidRuntime(9845):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I assume this is a issue that in my Manifest file in my project

so heres my Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.d4a.tobiasnow"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="system|signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_install_shortcut"
        android:label="@string/permlab_install_shortcut"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_uninstall_shortcut"
        android:label="@string/permlab_uninstall_shortcut"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.d4a.tobiasnow.permission.READ_SETTINGS"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_read_settings"
        android:label="@string/permlab_read_settings"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.d4a.tobiasnow.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_write_settings"
        android:label="@string/permlab_write_settings"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.d4a.tobiasnow.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.LauncherApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:largeHeap="@bool/config_largeHeap"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.Launcher"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.ToggleWeightWatcher"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home"
            android:label="@string/toggle_weight_watcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity android:name="dialer2.DialerActivity"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

          <activity android:name="dialer2.FragmentTab3"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.WallpaperPickerActivity"
            android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
            android:label="@string/pick_wallpaper"
            android:process=":wallpaper_chooser"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.WallpaperCropActivity"
            android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
            android:label="@string/crop_wallpaper"
            android:process=":wallpaper_chooser"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WallpaperCropper" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Debugging tools -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.MemoryDumpActivity"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home"
            android:label="@string/debug_memory_activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.MemoryTracker"
            android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled" >
        </service>

        <!-- Intent received used to prepopulate the default workspace. -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.PreloadReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Intent received used to install shortcuts from other applications -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.InstallShortcutReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Intent received used to uninstall shortcuts from other applications -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.UninstallShortcutReceiver"
            android:permission="com.android.launcher3.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- New user initialization; set up initial wallpaper -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.UserInitializeReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_INITIALIZE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.PackageChangedReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" >
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- The settings provider contains Home's data, like the workspace favorites -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.d4a.tobaisnow.LauncherProvider"
            android:authorities="com.d4a.tobiasnow.settings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="com.d4a.tobiasnow.permission.READ_SETTINGS"
            android:writePermission="com.d4a.tobiasnow.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.disable_beam_default"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I renamed the com.android.launcher3 package in the project to: com.d4a.tobaisnow

I have no idea what the issue is I've tried googling the issue for 5 hours now and no luck

any help/feedback would be amazing!

Thank in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are crashing in a `Runnable` (presumably) in `LauncherModel`, on line 526. Of course, we do not really know what this code is, as you decided not to supply the code that is causing your crash.

However, from the stack trace, it appears as though you are attempting to work with the `com.android.launcher3.LauncherProvider` `ContentProvider`, which is defended by the `com.android.launcher3.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permission. In a standard Launcher3 build, [that permission is `signatureOrSystem`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml). You are not signed by the Launcher3 app's signing key, and presumably your app is not installed on the system partition. Hence, you cannot hold this permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll look into it and let you know what I found out!